# Using a Value in write.csv

Tags: r, csv, automation

Maybe a simple question, but I am trying to automate a bit of code, including the write.csv process.

I want to use a character (Stationname, e.g. STN76) to name the csv, I have this:

```
write.csv(AbunData, file = Stationname)
```

Where the station name is the automated bit. Which sort of works, but without the .csv file encoding. I want to .csv to be

STN76.csv

or would would be even better!

STN76_Routput.csv

Cheers!

Comment: So maybe just `file = paste0(Stationname,".csv")`?

Comment: Worked a treat, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you include more details on exactly what you are doing you will probably get a more helpful answer :), but have you explored using `paste()` or `paste0()` to create the file names. E.g.:

```
file_name <- paste0("STN", SOME_NUMBER, "_Routput.csv")
```